# Reapplying macro font change to chartarea does not work

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code which changes all texts in a chart object to a specific size and font. Thing is the first time one runs the code it works like a charm. But if I change any part of the text within the chart and then re-run the code nothing happens.

E.g I run the code, then change the title heading to size 15 and font arial, then rerun macro, and nothing happens.

What can be wrong?

My code

```
With Selection

        .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 10
        .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
        .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoFalse

        End With
```

Comment: @pnuts, I think it really is.  You can test this as OP has described.  I think the issue is related to trying to style the whole chart by using `ChartArea`.  See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply the fonts/sizes to the `ChartArea` in order to propagate them down to the individual pieces, Excel stores that info at the `CharArea` level.  If you make a change to the one of the components (`ChartTitle`, `Axis`, etc.) and try to run your code again, there is no change on the `ChartArea`.  Seems that Excel does not propagate those changes "back up".  This makes sense since now the different items are styled differently.

The easiest way to deal with this is to reset the styles before you make your changes.  `ClearToMatchStyle` applied to the `Chart` (i.e. `ActiveChart` or `Selection.Parent` in your context) will do it.  It appears it will also make the change if you use a different font size or actually make a change to one of the `ChartArea.Format` properties (e.g. `Size`, `Name`, etc.).

**Code for the reset option**

```
ActiveChart.ClearToMatchStyle

With Selection

    .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 12
    .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoFalse

End With
```

Comment: This is more of an opinion: To see one of the effects of this, note that applying a font size of 12 does not actually make all the components a size of 12 (check the `ChartTitle`).  Mine goes to 14.4.  So Excel is taking your "request" to change the font size and applying it within the context of the style already applied.  Same happens after you make changes under the `ChartArea`; Excel applies what it thinks is appropriate.  Finally, applying formatting to charts is a real bear of a task with VBA.  You will end up touching every piece of the chart before you get what you want.  Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for all the information! I also noticed the "excel touch" when applying font size, mine went to 12 when I wanted it to go to 10. You mentioned earlier the memory, does that work similar to PivotTables (.ie with caches)?

Comment: I think it has less to do with caches and more to do with some sort of internal definition in a `ChartStyle` about how elements should be related by default.  That's me guessing though.

Comment: hmm ok. Very strange behaviour though. Thanks again!

Comment: The ClearToMatchStyle solution, was that by pure random logical feeling or was there some specific logic to that answer? I don't get exactly why resetting the styles should solve the issue although it does

Comment: There is a `Reset to Match Style` if you right click the Chart.  I just recorded a macro while hitting that.  Seemed like a good place to start.  That strategy applies to learning nearly all of Excel VBA. :)